# How can I make emacs respect "completion-ignored-extensions" when I hit TAB in the "Find File" buffer?

Tags: completion, customize

When I hit `C-x C-f` to open the "Find file" thing, I can hit `TAB` to open up a buffer called `*Completions*` that lists the possible filenames with the given prefix.

Sometimes I have a bunch of backup and intermediate files I want Emacs to ignore, but unfortunately, [as explained in the documentation,](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html):

> Emacs disregards `completion-ignored-extensions` when showing completion alternatives in the completion list.

So in a directory containing two files, `foo` and `foo~`, with `completion-ignored-extensions` set to `("~")`, tapping `TAB` lists both in the `*Completions*` buffer. Is there any way to change this behavior and list only `foo`?

Comment: The documentation for that variables says "It does not ignore them if all possible completions end in one of these strings or when displaying a list of completions." So (1) the behavior you observe is intended, (2) I think it probably still won't offer you to complete foo~, it's just listing it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear—I know it's not a bug; I'm just looking for a way to modify the default behavior. (I have these directories with a lot of source files, and it's basically listing three copies of everything: the source file, some intermediate compilation file that gets generated, and the backup file. It's a bit much.)

Comment: I just found this comment in minibuffer.el :)

"Bugs:

 - completion-all-sorted-completions lists all the completions, whereas
   it should only lists the ones that `try-completion' would consider.
   E.g.  it should honor completion-ignored-extensions."

Comment: Oh, huh. I figured it was intended since it was in the documentation. Well, hopefully someone has a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, vanilla Emacs is weak/broken wrt option `completion-ignored-extensions`.

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) there is no such problem. When a file name is ignored it is ignored completely; it is not shown in `*Completions*`.

And in Icicles you can toggle this ignoring off or on at any time during completion, using `C-.` in the minibuffer.

See 
[Icicles - File-Name Completion Tips](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Completion_Tips#completion-ignored-extensions).